# Compiz shortcut with two arrow keys

Tags: compiz

The "Put" functionality of CompizConfig Settings Manager is great. I'd like to be able to move windows to the desktop corners by using Super+Down/Up+Left/Right for this; is that possible? Whenever I try to set something like that it is just reset to "Disabled".

A workaround is of course to use the numeric pad, but I'd like to be able to do this on my EEE laptop as well without enabling and disabling NumLock all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design, it is not possible to create a keyboard shortcut that uses multiple non-[modifier keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modifier_key).

Imagine you've created shortcuts for both <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>. When you press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>, how will the computer know whether to execute the shortcut or keep waiting for more keys?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried to set these to use the arrow keys in the Put plugin before, but I do not believe it is possible if compiz resets the keys. You may have to resort to using your normal number keys at the top of the keyboard.

The arrow keys work otherwise though.

Comment: There is no problem with using arrow keys in the Put plugin. l0b0 is asking about creating keyboard shortcuts with *two* arrow keys, e.g. Super+Up+Left.

Comment: sorry I missed that minor detail at first.

Answer (score 0):

Using `xchainkeys`, you could define **key sequences**.

For an example, we use the same keys as in the answer of @ændrük;
<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> <kbd>Left</kbd>.
(That is pressing two keys at the same time, and then one alone - not all three at once in his example: <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>.)

You can define key sequences in `xchainkeys` in some variants, one way would be to define a group of key sequences starting with the same prefix - <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> in this case.

Then pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> only goes into a mode waiting for the next key (or timing out if you like).

Now, we could define:
<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> <kbd>Up</kbd>
<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> <kbd>Left</kbd>
<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> <kbd>Right</kbd>
Pressing the same keys again would insert the keys as pressed one time by default.

With other options, we can use:
<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> <kbd>Right</kbd> <kbd>Up</kbd> <kbd>Up</kbd>
without repeating the prefix key.